# How to resolve the issue in vscode after running flutter doctor?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Here's the error I'm getting after running flutter doctor:

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\Debnath Mondal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.
```

Comment: I think you must enhance your post, explain what you're trying to realize instead of simply paste your issue here.

Comment: Please list your ```flutter doctor``` logs

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the path that android threw in the error of an SDK that should be existed, and the folder was empty with no files.

in your case the path is

```
C:\Users\Debnath Mondal\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt
```

For me, I just installed the SDKs and the latest dependencies until I get rid of the errors.

and you can try to install the version of the SDK that shown in your message "Android SDK version 28.0.3"